# Apache thrift build on VxWorks

Tags: c++, thrift, vxworks

My aim is to use Apache thrift on one of our device having vxWorks 6.8 (C++).

I need steps to build thrift lib(.so) or sample application on vxWorks. It would be great help if someone could suggest way out. I am using Windriver Workbench 3.2 on windows 7 and target is PENTIUM3gnu. I can use boost but not C++ 11.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as someone who had to make Thrift build on a bog-normal Fedora PC, and as someone who knows the pain of making it work on embedded platforms¹, I can assure you that your confusion is at least partly caused by Thrift's sub-par build system.

I can't actually give you detailed descriptions on how to build it on vxWorks, but here's the general consensus on what needs to be done when building it on something that doesn't happen to be very similar to the maintainer's machines:

- massage all the `./configure` options, and explicitly disable every single thing you don't need. Even after much script fixing, I couldn't build the examples/tutorials, so I had to disable them
- explicitly state dependency paths. The autoconfigure scripts seem to have been modified in a manner that makes auto-detection of libraries work worse than it normally does with autoconf
- try to build. Find the places where for some reasons, the build system uses hardwired locations and hence fails
- rinse, repeat.

---

¹ OpenEmbedded, Android

Comment: Thank you Marcus. Trying to making it work on VXWorks 6.8 but getting many boost errors along with thrift like /cstdint.hpp:472:9: error: #error defaults not correct; you must hand modify boost/cstdint.hpp etc.  Have you ever tried building sample thrift application on VxWorks?

Comment: @AbhijitB as I said, no.